# parameter name omitted error for function returning enum

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a driver using hrtimer. I am getting the parameter name omitted for the following function definition

```
enum hrtimer_restart (hr_toggle)(struct hrtimer *hrt)
{

    <some code>

}
```

What is wrong with this code ? I have given a valid struct.

Update: I have also tried to use the same without the parenthesis for function name.
The result is same. I am using the standard arm gcc compiler now available in ubuntu arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm a little suprised that this definition actually works. Is there a reason you're not using `enum hrtimer_restart hr_toggle(struct hrtimer *hrt)`?

Comment: the above function is used in the later part of the code. There are no other issues with the compilation. Only the definition of this one function. I don't think its an issue with the return type. But I am not able make out what's causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Parameter name omitted" is the error given by GCC-family compilers when (naturally) a parameter's name is omitted in a function definition, which is not permitted in C.

The latest Clang and GCC versions actually don't object to the declaration above (assuming definitions for `struct hrtimer` and `enum hrtimer_restart`), so my guess is you're not using one of them and are instead using a different compiler that isn't perfectly compliant with the C spec. The code in the question is correct and shouldn't be rejected.

If so, it's probably not recognising that the function name is allowed to be in parentheses, and has incorrectly parsed `hrtimer_restart` as the function name, and `hr_toggle` as the type of the first parameter (and ...hasn't got as far as noticing `enum` isn't a return type before giving up - weird order to do things).

Removing the parentheses from the name, or preferably changing your compiler/compiler's settings, to something more perfectly compliant, should deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how this works but changing the *hrt to *t worked.

```
enum hrtimer_restart (hr_toggle)(struct hrtimer *t)
```

Works just fine. Weird but true. The paranthesis around the hr_toggle do not matter.

Comment: Maybe there is preprocessor symbol defined `hrt`. You could instruct your compiler to save preprocessed source to a file, and see what output it does.